# Why doesn't queue::push produce an object that goes out of scope?

Tags: c++

This might be a dumb question, but I am wondering: when a queue pushes an object, I learned that [it creates a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984095/stl-queue-push-behavior) (not a reference) before pushing the copy. I was wondering: where does this copy live in memory, and why isn't it destructed when the original object itself goes out of scope (given that the queue itself doesn't go out of scope)? I'm guessing it doesn't live in the stack frame the original object lived in, as it would be destructed?

For example, if I do:

```
std::queue<std::vector<float>> q;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  q.push(v);
}
```

Then `q` will still contain the vectors even if `v` goes out of scope.

Comment: "why isn't it destructed when the original object itself goes out of scope" Because it's a copy!!  That's the whole point, that the copy has its own independent lifetime.

Comment: Right, but I guess I'm curious how it differs in terms of where it lives in memory than the original object

Comment: [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) uses a [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as its underlying container.

Comment: Side note: `std::vector<int>` will not fit willingly in a `std::queue<std::vector<float>>`.

Comment: maybe you should start learning about C and C arrays, and the stack, and the heap, and dynamic memory allocation, those are fundamental things to learn to understand how C++ works under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering: where does this copy live in memory

[`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is a container adaptor which uses [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as the underlying container by default. [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is a class template, which has a template argument for the allocator, which is [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) by default.
So unless you say otherwise, [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) manages memory with `new`/`delete`.

(More specifically, memory is acquired by calling `::operator new`)

> and why isn't it destructed when the original object itself goes out of scope

Why would it? The queue has created a copy of the object on `push()`, and any change to the original has no effect on the copy that is stored in the queue.

> I'm guessing it doesn't live in the stack frame the original object lived in, as it would be destructed?

Yes, the object in the queue doesn't live on the stack, only the original does. The object in the queue is destroyed when the queue is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Correct understanding of **storage classes** is mandatory for any C++ programmer. It's one of the basics of **object lifetime management**.
C++ defines 3+1 storage classes:

1. **automatic:**
   The object's lifetime is bound to the defining/constructing scope. This includes function local ordinary objects, as well as class data fields. In the later case the fields lifetime is bound to the lifetime of nesting class'd object instance; that is when an object instance of a class is destructed, all its fields are atomatically destructed too.
2. **Static:**
   Objects in this class normally outlive other classes; their lifetime starts - roughly - with the program execution and ends when program finishes. These objects normally have either *external* or *internal* ***linkage*** - depending on declaration specifiers and scope.
3. **Dynamic:**
   Objects lifetime is independent of the construction scope and depends on the program logic. Objects can be destroyed on demand, in response to calling specific API functions.
4. (3+1)**Thread local:**
   Similar to **static storage** but lifetime of objects is bound to the thread that uses uses them as part of its running function. When thread normally stops execution, these objects are destructed.

Back to the original question:
All `std` containers - ecxept `array` and `initializer_list` - create their elements as dynamic objects. The elemens are **owned** by the container instance; i.e. when a container object is destructed, all its elements are destructed too. But - apart from the two containers that use atomatic duration for their elements(and construct all the elements upon their own construction) - every other container has elements with dynamic storage. Dynamic storage **can(not must) be implemented on free store(heap), but there are cases where they use the container specific memory too (SSO, SBO, `std::variant`, `std::optional`, `static_vector`...).

A C++ programmer is supposed to know the distinction between these storage classes, as well as their use cases and how each container in his program/code base stores its data. The details of dynamic storage management should not be of concern, unless domain-specific demands( embedded, SIMD, ...) require or designing a special container is intended.

Comment: Note that `std::array` can still be stored dynamically (e.g. `std::make_unique<std::array<int, 10>>()`) and also statically or even with thread local storage.

Comment: @digito_evo that is the storage class of the container, not the elements. There's no dynamic construction/destruction happening on elements; the array is constructed and so are the elements, the array gets destructed and so will the elements. Elements are always automatically constructed and destructed.

Comment: That means it really doesn't force automatic storage upon us. It depends on the choice of the programmer where to store its elements. However with other containers, the default choice is dynamic storage regardless of where the container object is stored.

Comment: @digito_evo *atomatic storage* is a weak term. If the nesting scope has other storage, then the automatic object inherits that storage. But detailed terminology calls for language-lawyer and overcomplicates the matter; not beneficial for the average programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It lives in dynamically allocated storage owned by underlying container of the queue, which is a `std::deque<std::vector<float>>` data member.