# Can std::string overload "substr" for rvalue *this and steal resources?

Tags: c++, c++11, substr, rvalue-reference

It just occurred to me I noticed that `std::string`'s `substr` operation could be much more efficient for rvalues when it could steal the allocated memory from `*this`.

The Standard library of N3225 contains the following member function declaration of `std::string`

```
basic_string substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos) const;
```

Can an implementation that could implement an optimized `substr` for rvalues overload that and provide two versions, one of which could reuse the buffer for rvalue strings?

```
basic_string substr(size_type pos = 0) &&;
basic_string substr(size_type pos, size_type n) const;
```

I imagine the rvalue version could be implemented as follows, reusing the memory of `*this` an setting `*this` to a moved-from state.

```
basic_string substr(size_type pos = 0) && {
  basic_string __r;
  __r.__internal_share_buf(pos, __start + pos, __size - pos);
  __start = 0; // or whatever the 'empty' state is
  return __r;
}
```

Does this work in an efficient fashion on common string implementations or would this take too much housekeeping?

Comment: Wouldn’t that leak memory? After all, we are only stealing a part of the memory, not the whole block …

Comment: @Konrad we need to remember that we were stealing memory and when freeing it we need to back-offset it to the origin.

Comment: Note that strings in some other languages like Java do this - some problems include that if you allocate a large string, extract a small substring from it, and then release the large one, you've still got the data for the large string hanging around in memory as long as you're using the substring.

Comment: That's basically copy-on-write for substrings, no?

Comment: I think it would probably take too much housekeeping to be worthwhile. Along the other concerns, it doesn't seem like it would play very well with the short string optimization; you'd probably have to disable it when taking a substring of an already-"short" string.

Comment: c++ standard lib needs immutable strings and vectors.

Comment: The `pos = 0` (left substring) special case wouldn't need housekeeping.

Comment: I have a faint memory of this being discussed in committee, but I can't find any documentation of it.  It may have been just an informal discussion.  I believe a vendor could add this optimization at his discretion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, an implementation cannot add an overload that steals the source, since that would be detectable:

```
std::string s="some random string";
std::string s2=std::move(s).substr(5,5);
assert(s=="some random string"); 
assert(s2=="rando");
```

The first assert would fail if the implementation stole the data from `s`, and the C++0x wording essentially outlaws copy on write.

Secondly, this wouldn't necessarily be an optimization anyway: you'd have to add additional housekeeping in `std::string` to handle the case that it's a substring of a larger string, and it would mean keeping large blocks around when there was no longer any strings referencing the large string, just some substring of it.

Comment: This isn't true, since `::std::move` is basically saying "Please, steal data from the source, it's just fine!".

Comment: `std::move` casts it to an rvalue, but the standard still specifies what is permitted on that rvalue. Since the only specified overload of `substr` is `const`, it can't modify the value. If the implementation provides an overload that does, this is detectable.

Comment: Note that this is quite different from `s2=std::move(s)`, since there is an overload of `operator=` which takes an rvalue reference, so you cannot rely on the state of `s` afterwards --- you can detect differences between implementations, but you don't know what to expect.

Comment: The first assert will probably fail, since the value of s is undefined after passing it to std::move...

Comment: @Chris: No, it isn't. That's my point: `s` has a defined value unless something explicit is done that modifies that value. `std::move(s)` is just a wrapper for `static_cast<std::string&&>(s)`, and doesn't itself change the value of `s`. `substr` is a `const` member function, so doesn't change the value either. This is therefore a valid snippet with defined behaviour.

Comment: @Anthony, n3225 says "If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument.". Does this not apply to the implicit object parameter of member functions added by overload resolution? When we say `std::move(s).substr(...)`, and afterwards still use `s` then it seems to me we would violate that assumption.

Comment: Yes, but `std::move(s).substr(..)` doesn't bind anything to an rvalue reference **parameter**. `std::move` takes an lvalue reference and creates an rvalue reference. `substr` is a `const` member function, so the implicit object parameter is a `const` lvalue reference. As I said already, this is quite different from `s2=std::move(s)`, where `s` **is** bound to the rvalue reference parameter of `operator=`.

Comment: @Anthony ah I see now. I was in the impression that if the impl would overload `substr` with an ref-qualifier overload, that then it would bind to such a parameter. But since in the spec there is no such overload, the impl cannot simply add that overload and then argue with "If a function argument ...". I see it clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and maybe it should be proposed to the standards committee, or maybe implemented in a library. I don't really know how valuable the optimization would be. And that would be an interesting study all on its own.

When gcc grows support for r-value `this`, someone ought to try it and report how useful it is.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few string classes out there implementing copy-on-write. But I wouldn't recommend adding yet another string type to your project unless really justified.

Check out the discussion in [Memory-efficient C++ strings (interning, ropes, copy-on-write, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116040/memory-efficient-c-strings-interning-ropes-copy-on-write-etc)